# Powershell statements

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
while(($dois = Read-Host 'Server Lookup Y/N') -eq 'n') {
    switch($dois) {
        'Y' {
            do {
                Clear-Host
                try {
                    $SN = Read-Host 'Enter Server Name'
                    $lookup = Get-ADComputer -identity $SN -Properties memberof, dnshostname | Select-Object dnshostname, memberof |
                        ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File '.\extract.json' | code .\extract.json
                }
                catch { Write-Warning "$SN does not exist, please input a valid Server Name." }
            }until($lookup)
        }
        'N' { Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan 'Ending Script' }
    }
    exit
}
```

I feel like I've been working on this for way too long and it is burning me out. The script was intended to be used as a tool to pull some server properties and then export it out to a JSON file, it was working fine but it wasn't interactive and that's where I started expanding and now have issues, I added a user option for Y/N and when I select N the script executes as intended but the issue, when they select option Y, is that at the end of the export the shell keeps asking to enter a server name but what I want is for the shell to present the server lookup y/n option as when initially running the script also the warning doesn't get trigger when they type in an incorrect server name.

Comment: Do you really need `'N' { Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan 'Ending Script' }` ? You should just enter the loop only if `($dois = Read-Host 'Server Lookup Y/N') -eq 'Y'`. That would simplify it so much

Comment: I frankly do not need it again I feel I overthought the whole scheme of things... I removed that part but right after exporting the file, it goes back to enter the server name instead of going back to server lookup i want to go back to it and then if decided to start the loop again, also unable to execute the catch statement.. for some reason I think this has to do with the until statement. I was not able to create a variable for converting/exporting since im piping the results of get-adcomputer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your current code, `until($lookup)` will loop indefinitely because `$lookup` will always be null, because `Out-File` doesn't produce any output. You could try the following using a boolean at the end of the `try` block, if `Get-ADComputer` didn't fail then you can ensure there was an output to the file.

```
$lookup = $false
switch($dois) {
    'Y' {
        do {
            try {
                $SN = Read-Host 'Enter Server Name'
                Get-ADComputer -identity $SN -Properties memberof, dnshostname |
                    Select-Object dnshostname, memberof |
                    ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 |
                    Out-File '.\extract.json'
                # signal to stop the `do` loop
                $lookup = $true
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning "$SN does not exist, please input a valid Server Name."
            }
        }
        until($lookup)
    }
    'N' {
        ....
    }
}
```

I would personally use something like this, [`.PromptForChoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) helps a lot ensuring the user choses a valid option (`Y` or `N`) and using a [`try` / `catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3) to verify the computer exists. If the cmdlet fails to find a computer with the provided input the nothing gets exported. Its also worth noting that in case the user decides to continue to query more servers then the `extract.json` would get overwritten on each loop iteration (assuming a computer could be found).

```
# should we enter this loop? if `No` then the script just exits
while($Host.UI.PromptForChoice('', 'Server Lookup?', ('&Yes', '&No'), 0) -eq 0) {
    try {
        $sn = Read-Host 'Enter Server Name'
        Get-ADComputer $sn -Properties memberof, dnshostname |
            Select-Object dnshostname, memberof |
            ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 |
            Set-Content '.\extract.json'

        # `Out-Content` and `Set-Content` don't produce output
        # hence the pipe to `code` was incorrect
        code .\extract.json
    }
    catch {
        # if the user input was not valid or the computer couldn't be found
        Write-Warning "Input is invalid or '$sn' does not exist."
    }
}
```